# Mongo DB find query taking too much time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have worked with MySQL and PHP project earlier for a iPhone app, but when storage data size increases with time, client moved with NodeJS and MongoDB.

We have made a new version of app with Mongo database, which is working fine with few records.

But when we have migrated MySQL database into MongoDB, it has consumed almost 2GB space at server.

Our app having large numbers of users and its related data.

And now we are stuck that find records (20 records) taking so much time (4 to 5 seconds) which leads to unwanted time consumption in the app, and users irritated in most of activities in app.

Comment: Are you searching for _id's? If not, have you indexed the other keys for your search queries?

Comment: Client moved to MongoDB for storag reasons? That wasn't a very intelligent move...I am wondering if the DB and app is setup with same ideas...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this section of the documentation MongoDB talking about Performance Optimization.

As the documentation displayed options are:

- Create Indexes to Support Queries
- Use Projections to Return Only Necessary Data

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add indexes to your collection.

`ensureIndex` command creates an index on the collection. It will improve the speed of your queries significantly. The indexes will have to be created according to the queries you use.

Please follow this documentation:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-creation/